# Connect to academic VPN from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn

I'm trying to install Gurobi on my EC2 Ubuntu server, and I would like to use my academic license for that. To do that, I need to connect EC2 to my school's VPN.

But my problem is while I follow all the step from my school's website to establish vpn using Cisco AnyConnect, it seems like not having any effect. And I got a message from Gurobi while verifying my license says that `host name ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com not recognized as belonging to an academic domain.`

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that EC2 workers are in AWS domain.

If your licence is working based on a domain of a system registered, you may need to configure the domain of the Ubuntu machine as same as your school academic domain(make sure that you have necessary privilege to change the domain).

**EDIT:**

Host name of the machine can be changed by editing the file 
`/etc/hostname`
(by using the terminal `sudo vi /etc/hostname`)
replace the existing name with your appropriate school domain
*Ex:* 
If your school domain name is "myschool.local"
you can change the hostname to "machinename.myschool.local", ("machinename" may be your choice)

Restart your machine once you are done.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Or like what service/keyword should I be looking into? (Also I'm the creator of that EC2 so I think I have the privilege to change the domain) Thanks!

Comment: I have added the steps to change the host name of your choice in my EDIT.